# An error when using the StreamProvider (Could not find the correct Provider<List<Building>> above this AllBuildings Widget)

Tags: flutter, dart, provider

This is my main file where I am using a StreamProvider inside a MultiProvider. My providers are wrapping the MaterialApp so that other widgets that come after has access to my list of buildings.

```
void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final FirestoreService _db = FirestoreService();
    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        StreamProvider(
          create: (BuildContext context) => _db.getBuildings(),
        )
      ],
      child: MaterialApp(
        theme: ThemeData.light().copyWith(
          primaryColor: Hexcolor(kUntGreen),
        ),
        home: NavigationDrawer(
          title: 'Campus Explorer',
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

In my NavigationDrawer I render the selected page using a switch statement

```
class _NavigationDrawerState extends State<NavigationDrawer> {
  int _selectedItem = 0;
  Widget _getPage(selectedIndex) {
    switch (selectedIndex) {
      case 0:
        return MyPoints();
      case 1:
        return AllBuildings();
      case 2:
        return UNTApplications();
      default:
        return new Text("Error");
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(widget.title),
        ),
        drawer: Drawer(...),
        body: _getPage(_selectedItem),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

When I try to get access to my list using my provider in the following code:

```
class AllBuildings extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var buildings = Provider.of<List<Building>>(context);
    return Scaffold(
      body: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: buildings.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, i) {
          var building = buildings[i];
          return ListTile(
            leading: Text(building.buildingName),
            title: Text(building.buildingId),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I get the following errors:

```
════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following ProviderNotFoundException was thrown building AllBuildings(dirty):
Error: Could not find the correct Provider<List<Building>> above this AllBuildings Widget

This likely happens because you used a `BuildContext` that does not include the provider
of your choice. There are a few common scenarios:

- The provider you are trying to read is in a different route.

  Providers are "scoped". So if you insert of provider inside a route, then
  other routes will not be able to access that provider.

- You used a `BuildContext` that is an ancestor of the provider you are trying to read.

  Make sure that AllBuildings is under your MultiProvider/Provider<List<Building>>.
  This usually happen when you are creating a provider and trying to read it immediatly.

  For example, instead of:

 
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Provider<Example>(
      create: (_) => Example(),
      // Will throw a ProviderNotFoundError, because `context` is associated
      // to the widget that is the parent of `Provider<Example>`
      child: Text(context.watch<Example>()),
    ),
  }
 

  consider using `builder` like so:


  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Provider<Example>(
      create: (_) => Example(),
      // we use `builder` to obtain a new `BuildContext` that has access to the provider
      builder: (context) {
        // No longer throws
        return Text(context.watch<Example>()),
      }
    ),
  }
 

If none of these solutions work, consider asking for help on StackOverflow:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/flutter

The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  AllBuildings file:///C:/Users/HP/Desktop/Flutter/campus_explorer/lib/navigation/navigation_drawer.dart:27:16
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#0      Provider._inheritedElementOf (package:provider/src/provider.dart:269:7)
#1      Provider.of (package:provider/src/provider.dart:221:30)
#2      AllBuildings.build (package:campus_explorer/pages/all_buildings.dart:8:30)
#3      StatelessElement.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4620:28)
#4      ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4546:15)
```

I tried to not use the Navigation Drawer, instead i used push to push the page on the stack.
I also tried to use the streamProvider directly without the MultiProvider. Nothing I tried worked

This is my FirestoreService where I get the buildings. I have another function that is addBuilding() but I am not using it at this time.

```
class FirestoreService {
  Firestore _db = Firestore.instance;
  Stream<List<Building>> getBuildings() {
    return _db
        .collection('buildings')
        .orderBy('building_name', descending: false)
        .snapshots()
        .map((snapshot) => snapshot.documents
            .map((document) => Building.fromJson(document.data))
            .toList());
  }

  Future<void> addBuilding() {
    var dataMap = Map<String, dynamic>();
    return _db.collection('buildings').add(dataMap);
  }
}
```

Comment: What does your getBuildings functions returns?

Comment: It returns  Stream<List<Building>>. This is the function: ``Stream<List<Building>> getBuildings()``

Comment: I don't think this is the problem, but at least it's probably not a good idea to have `final FirestoreService _db = FirestoreService();` in your build function. Better keep it outside. Though maybe this is ok, depending how Firestore works internally.

Comment: I just tried taking out and that didn't change anything. I am still getting the same errors.

Comment: Consider typing `StreamProvider<List<Building>>` to make sure.

Comment: I would get this error ``error: A value of type 'Stream<List<Building>>' can't be returned from method 'getBuildings' because it has a return type of 'StreamProvider<List<Building>>'. (return_of_invalid_type at [campus_explorer] lib\services\firestore_service.dart:9)``

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found what was wrong with my code. I had an extra forward slash in my import statement.

```
import 'package:campus_explorer/models//building.dart';
```

Instead of this:

```
import 'package:campus_explorer/models/building.dart';
```

I am not sure why that might cause such an issue, but I am assuming it was referring to the wrong type.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Stream<List<Building>> getBuildings() {
    return _db
        .collection('buildings')
        .orderBy('building_name', descending: false)
        .snapshots()
        .map((query) => query.documents)
            .map((snapshot) => snapshot
            .map((document) => Building.fromJson(document.data))
            .toList());
  }
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it is giving me the same exact error.